# Cannot load pyserial in eclipse to access with pydev

Tags: pydev, pyserial

Unable install pyserial module to use in eclipse pydev. Any suggestions as how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

First, check that the Python interpreter is correctly set inside Pydev (Window->Preferences->PyDev->Interpreters->Python Interpreters). I would suggest you try a new "Auto-Config" to force PyDev into adding all the correct paths to PYTHONPATH. To be really sure, delete your current interpreter and add a completely new one.

Next, open a new Python console (the small icon with a plus sign in the top of the Console view). Select "PyDev console" and then "Python console" when asked. The first lines you see there will be the used Python interpreter (in my case a Linux system):

```
/usr/bin/python 2.7.12 (default, Jul  1 2016, 15:12:24) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
>>>
```

In the console, try importing PySerial:

```
>>> import serial
```

(Note: It is "import serial" not "import pyserial").
If this gives you an error message, double check that you really installed PySerial (you will find it in the folder dist-packages/serial (on Linux) or site-packages/serial (on Windows)).